# Hugo based website with widget menus also being dropdown menus?

Tags: html, hyperlink, menu, hugo

I am using the hugo-academic theme for a webpage. Is it possible to have a widget's menu link (from the homepage) also be a dropdown menu
[like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNKt1.png)

So when I am scrolling down the main page (homepage) it would highlight the widget I am seeing at the moment (as a hugo academic page would do), but at the same time, it is a drop-down menu in case I want to go to more specific webpages.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example if you want to put the "projects" widget in the home. You only need to put in the sub-menu url an # to link your widget

```
[[main]]
  name = "Projects"
  url = "#projects"
  identifier = "projects"
  weight = 1
  
[[main]]
  name = "Project 1"
  url = "#projects1"
  parent = "projects"
  weight = 1

[[main]]
  name = "Project 2"
  url = "#projects1"
  parent = "projects"
  weight = 2
```

If you have a widget_page "Project", you need to put the root project and then the #

```
url = "projects/#project1"
```

You can see my repo for an example: github.com/valentinaandrade/movid-site

Comment: I see. What I meant actually is to have the first item to be the widget in the homepage (so URL: #projects) and then the sub-menus would link to other pages. However, when I do that and click on the projects link, it doesn't take me to the widget section in the homepage.